Unable to dynamically set date to ngx-daterangepicker-material
Trying to set a date value doesn't work when data is being fetched from API and ngModel is set to an undefined array object property.
<div
  *ngFor="let substitute of secondarySubstitutes; let i = index"
  style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-direction: row"
>
  <input
    type="text"
    matInput
    ngxDaterangepickerMd
    [locale]="{ applyLabel: 'ok', format: 'DD-MM-YYYY' }"
    [(ngModel)]="secondarySubstitutes[i].startDate"
    name="daterange"
  />

  <input
    type="text"
    matInput
    ngxDaterangepickerMd
    [locale]="{ applyLabel: 'ok', format: 'DD-MM-YYYY' }"
    [(ngModel)]="secondarySubstitutes[i].endDate"
    name="daterange"
  />
</div>

secondaryAssignedPerson = [ /// data to loop over ]
public secondarySubstitutes: any = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.secondaryAssignedPerson.map((elm, i) => {
      this.secondarySubstitutes.push({
        fullName: elm.fullName,
        userEmail: elm.userEmail,
        userPhone: elm.userPhone,
        userPhoneCode: elm.userPhoneCode,
        startDate: elm.startDate,
        endDate: elm.endDate,
      });

      // this.updateDate();
      console.log(this.secondarySubstitutes);
    });
  }

If case of predefined ngValue property, it works as shown here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-daterangepicker-material-for-angular8-y48qwb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
but not in above defined case:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-daterangepicker-material-for-angular8-ukjsdo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Solved, instead of providing individual date, i.e "secondarySubstitutes[i].startDate" or "secondarySubstitutes[i].endDate", it has to be provided a range, so the ngModel instead should be in my case 'secondarySubstitutes[i].date'
{
...secondarySubstitutes,
date: {
startDate: elm.startDate,
endDate: elm.endDate,
}
}
working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-daterangepicker-material-for-angular8-mrq7pe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

constructor(){
// Initialize secondarySubstitutes as needed
// For example:
this.secondarySubstitutes = [
  { startDate: '', endDate: '' }, // Provide default values
  { startDate: '', endDate: '' },
  // Add more as required
];
}

ngOnInit() {
   this.fetchData(); // Assuming you have a method to fetch data
}
fetchData() { 
  this.someService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
  this.secondaryAssignedPerson = data;
  this.populateSubstitutes(); // Call method to populate secondarySubstitutes
});}
populateSubstitutes() {
this.secondarySubstitutes = this.secondaryAssignedPerson.map((elm) => ({
fullName: elm.fullName,
userEmail: elm.userEmail,
userPhone: elm.userPhone,
userPhoneCode: elm.userPhoneCode,
startDate: elm.startDate,
endDate: elm.endDate,
}));
}


Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe it is the best approach?
